# mousemove event on 2 overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 overlapping divs and need the same mousemove event to be executed on both.  I cant use nested divs with bubbling effect.
 How can I do that? I cant use nested divs with bubbling effect.

```js
$(".one").mousemove(function(){
  console.log("something")
})

$(".two").mousemove(function(){
  console.log("something else")
})
```

```css
.one{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
 
    
}
.two{
    color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  
 
    <div class="one">
        Content one
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        Content two
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can trigger the other div mouse move event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".one").mousemove(function(){
  console.log("something");
});

$(".two").mousemove(function(){
  console.log("something else");
  $(".one").mousemove();
});
```

```css
.one{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
 
    
}
.two{
    color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  opacity: .95;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
        Content one
</div>
<div class="two">
        Content two
</div>
```